# How to preview a report A and print Report B directly?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, printing, rdlc

I have two report for two pattern. Both report use same dataset and parameters.
Report A was inserted in a ReportViewer for showing preview in winform.
But when user click a print button on toolbar. Printer will print a report B.

**In VB.Net at Load Event**

```
      Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

            Me.MACHINESTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.MACHINES)       
            Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report_A.rdlc"
            Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("MACHINES", Me.MACHINESBindingSource)
            Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
            Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
            Dim params(1) As ReportParameter
            params(0) = New ReportParameter("pTest", "AAAAAAA")            
            Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)
            Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
       End Sub
```

According above code. It will display Report A in reportViewer1.

**In Click Print Button Event** it will handle when user click print button on toolbar.
I only change path from **Report A** to  **Report B**.

```
      Private Sub ReportViewer1_Print(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReportViewer1.Print

                Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report_B.rdlc"                  
                Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("MACHINES", Me.MACHINESBindingSource)

                Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
                Dim params(1) As ReportParameter
                params(0) = New ReportParameter("pTest", "BBBBBBB")    
                Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)               
End Sub
```

But It isn't work .Printer can print Report B to the paper. But "MACHINES" -filled data from Report_A isn't display.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put two report viewer on form and set. report viewer 2 visible to false ?

Edit: this should be comment. Typing from phone